# How to get value in array in asp-classic

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

The array contents are like this ..

```
 str = "penalty: 6, ord: 1, ot: 0, fe: 7, rs: 7"
```

Arrays can be 3 ~ 10 depending on the situation.

How do you put variables in this way?

```
aa = 6

bb = 1

cc = 0

dd = 7

ee = 7
```

I tried this, but it does not work anymore.

```
 str_arr=Split(str,",") 
 if_num=UBound(str_arr)
 redim str_arr1(if_num) 
 For k=0 To eval(if_num) 
   str_arr1(k)=Split(str_arr(k),":")
  name = str_arr1(k)(0)
  num = str_arr1(k)(1)
Next
```

Comment: The code is a bit mixed up, its hard to follow what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the values of the string variable `str` into an array? Or, are you wanting to assign each value from the string variable `str` to their own variables? Because what you are asking for and what is written in the code don't seem to correlate??

Comment: thanks for replying to my queries, oh wait you didn't. Just wanting a quick fix so you don't have to think for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you  need is the `Split()` VBScript method, and store the results in a Dictionary object.

I wrote a generic function that takes a raw string, main separator, and sub separator which returns such a Dictionary object, that you can iterate to see the values:

```vbs
Function DoubleSplit(rawValue, mainSeparator, subSeparator)
    Dim oResult, arrMainParts, arrSubParts
    Dim x, curMainPart

    'using Dictionary as key/value collection
    Set oResult = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'split raw value by the main separator
    arrMainParts = Split(rawValue, mainSeparator)

    'iterate over main parts, split each by the sub separator
    For x=0 To UBound(arrMainParts)
        curMainPart = arrMainParts(x)
        arrSubParts = Split(curMainPart, subSeparator)
        If UBound(arrSubParts)=1 Then
            'adding to result only if there are both key and value
            oResult(arrSubParts(0)) = arrSubParts(1)
        End If

        'prevent memory leaks
        Erase arrSubParts
    Next

    'prevent memory leaks
    Erase arrMainParts

    'assign function return value
    Set DoubleSplit = oResult
End Function
```

Usage example, using the data given in the question:

```vbs
Dim str, myDictionary, key
str = "penalty: 6, ord: 1, ot: 0, fe: 7, rs: 7"
Set myDictionary = DoubleSplit(str, ", ", ": ")
For Each key In myDictionary.Keys
    Response.Write("Name is " & key & ", value is: " & myDictionary(key) & "<br />")
Next

'prevent memory leaks
Set myDictionary = Nothing
```

Comment: They can't even write a coherent question or bother to reply to genuine queries so what does doing it for them accomplish?

Comment: @Lankymart tried making it as generic as possible so others will find it useful.

Comment: What you actually do is to encourage people to keep asking bad questions because they get their answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard its an excellent answer. I just think that providing quality answers to poor questions just encourages more poor questions.

Comment: @Lankymart usually I'd agree with you. However when I can give a useful answer, even for poor question, I'll do it. I do understand what OP wants, after long years of doing similar string analysis myself. I played with the idea of editing the question to make it better and clarify what's the real need, but it would be a drastic change, so not sure. All in all, encouraging bad questions is a "collateral damage" here. :)

Comment: @BDL see my reply to Lankymart please.